# Does urllib2.urlopen() support no_proxy environment variable?

Tags: python, proxy, environment-variables, urllib2, urllib

`urllib.urlopen()`'s [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) mentions that the `http_proxy`/`ftp_proxy` environment variables can be used to specify a proxy that should be used for the URL opening like this:

> ```
> % http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
> % export http_proxy
> % python
> ```

It also mentions that `no_proxy` environment variable can be used to prevent using proxy for the specified sites like this:

```
export no_proxy="cern.ch,ncsa.uiuc.edu,some.host:8080"
```

I use `urllib2` instead of `urllib`, but its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) doesn't explicitly mention the possibility of using `no_proxy`. Can I use the `no_proxy` environment variable as well? Will it work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There was a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6894) in this, but it works like in `urllib` now.